# Pass multiple formatting arguments to logging function as tuple

Tags: python, logging, arguments

To pass multiple arguments with logging, I am using extra dictionary as below.

```
import logging

class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, fmt=None, datefmt=None, style='%'):
        custom_fmt = "%(asctime)s | %(levelname)-7s | %(c2)-10s | %(c1)-10s | %(message)s"
        super().__init__(custom_fmt, datefmt, style)

    def format(self, record):
        record.__dict__.setdefault('c1', '')
        record.__dict__.setdefault('c2', '')
        return super().format(record)

def setup_logging():
    logger = logging.getLogger('sample')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    formatter = CustomFormatter()

    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    return logger

def main():
    logger = setup_logging()
    logger.info('main msg')
    logger.info('main msg', extra={'c1': 'context1', 'c2': 'context2'})
    logger.info('main msg', extra={'c1': 'context1'})
    logger.info('main msg', extra={'c2': 'context2'})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output

```
2023-08-09 16:29:40,718 | INFO    |            |            | main msg
2023-08-09 16:29:40,724 | INFO    | context2   | context1   | main msg
2023-08-09 16:29:40,724 | INFO    |            | context1   | main msg
2023-08-09 16:29:40,725 | INFO    | context2   |            | main msg
```

The disadvantage of above solution is laborious dictionary definition, especially when there is only 1 contextual column. I am trying to make this work without dictionary, i.e.

```
    logger.info('main msg')
    logger.info('main msg', 'context1', 'context2')
    logger.info('main msg', None, 'context1')
    logger.info('main msg', 'context2')
```